Implementation of a `shared_any`
Below is an implementation of a shared_any:
#include <typeindex>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <compare>

class shared_any
{
public:
    shared_any() noexcept = default;

    template<class T, class ... Args>
    explicit shared_any(std::type_identity<T>, Args&&... args):
        m_holder{std::type_identity<T>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {}

    ~shared_any()
    { reset(); }

    shared_any(shared_any&& other) noexcept:
        m_holder{std::exchange(other.m_holder, holder{})}
    {}

    shared_any& operator=(shared_any&& other) noexcept
    {
        reset();
        m_holder = std::exchange(other.m_holder, m_holder);
        return *this;
    }

    shared_any(shared_any const& other):
        m_holder{other.m_holder}
    { m_holder.inc_usecount(); }

    shared_any& operator=(shared_any const& other)
    {
        shared_any tmp{other};
        *this = std::move(tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    template<class T>
    T* get_if() const noexcept
    { return m_holder.get_if<T>(); }

    void reset() noexcept
    {
        m_holder.dec_usecount();
        m_holder = holder{};
    }

    auto operator<=>(shared_any const&) const = default;

    auto use_count() const
    { return m_holder.usecount!=nullptr? *m_holder.usecount : static_cast<size_t>(0); }

private:
    static void noop(void*) {}

    struct holder
    {
        holder() = default;

        template<class T, class ... Args>
        explicit holder(std::type_identity<T>, Args&&... args):
            pointer{new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)},
            current_type{std::type_index{typeid(T)}},
            usecount{new size_t(1)},
            destroy{[](void* obj){ delete static_cast<T*>(obj);}}
        {}

        auto operator<=>(holder const& other) const noexcept
        { return std::compare_three_way{}(pointer, other.pointer); }

        void inc_usecount() noexcept
        { ++(*usecount); }

        void dec_usecount() noexcept
        {
            if(usecount != nullptr)
            {
                --(*usecount);
                if(usecount == 0)
                {
                    destroy(pointer);
                    delete usecount;
                }
            }
        }

        template<class T>
        T* get_if() const noexcept
        {
            if(current_type == std::type_index{typeid(T)})
            { return static_cast<T*>(pointer); }
            return nullptr;
        }

        void* pointer = nullptr;
        std::type_index current_type = std::type_index{typeid(void)};
        size_t* usecount = nullptr;
        void (*destroy)(void*) = noop;
    };

    holder m_holder;
};

For now, I do not need any thread-safe ref-counting. Also I realize that I potentially have a leak in case one of the two new expressions in holder throws an exception, though new size_t should never throw in practice.

What is the cleanest way to fix the potential memory leak?
Are there any other issues that I have not thought of?

Smoke-testing seems fine: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7zz499aaa

Why not just use std::shared_ptr<std::any>? I don't believe there's any need for user counting outside of multithreading where it is important.

@ALX23z. This becomes a pointer to a pointer.

Reuse std::shared_ptr
The reason to make a shared_any is to avoid the double pointer indirection from std::shared_ptr<std::any>. However, you can still make use of std::shared_ptr. For example, you could use a std::shared_ptr<void> with a custom deleter. Then you just need to add the "any" part somehow.
Of course you can only store one pointer in a std::shared_ptr, but you need that to point to the object itself, as well as to the type tag. To solve this issue, consider creating a base class for tagged objects that just contains the type tag, and a templated derived class that stores the actual type:
struct TaggedObjectBase {
    std::type_index tag;
};

template<typename T>
struct TaggedObject: TaggedObjectBase {
    T object;

    template<typename... Args>
    TaggedObject(Args&&... args):
        TaggedObjectBase{std::type_index{typeid(T)}}, 
        object{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
};

The trick is that you can store a pointer to a derived class in a std::shared_pointer to a base class.
So a very basic class using this could look like:
struct SharedObject {
    std::shared_ptr<TaggedObjectBase> pointer;

    template<typename T>
    SharedObject(T&& t):
        pointer(std::make_shared<TaggedObject<T>>(std::forward<T>(t))) {}

    template<typename T>
    T* get_if() {
        if (pointer && pointer->tag == std::type_index{typeid(T)}) {
            return &std::static_pointer_cast<TaggedObject<T>>(pointer)->object;
        } else {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    …
};

